# Continue execution after a particular condition is satisfied in Simpy

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I am new to Simpy and am trying to implement a simple simulation where the process must wait until a condition is False and when the condition becomes True it has to continue with the rest of the process.
Consider the simple code:

```
import simpy
import random

condition_flag = 0

def car(env):
     while True:
         global condition_flag
         #wait for the condition to become true
         while(condition_flag != 1):
             pass
         #reset condition flag
         condition_flag = 0

         print('Start parking at %d' % env.now)
         parking_duration = 5
         yield env.timeout(parking_duration)

         print('Start driving at %d' % env.now)
         trip_duration = 2
         yield env.timeout(trip_duration)

def some_condition(env):
    while True:
        global condition_flag
        rand_num = random.randrange(0, 10)
        if rand_num > 8:
            condition_flag = 1
        yield env.timeout(1)


env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(car(env))
env.process(some_condition(env))
env.run(until=15)
```

The above example is continuously waiting at the `while` condition in `car` process.
Is this the right way to do? If not how can this be taken up?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT & EXTENSION**(since I am not able to comment this big data)**:**
From @Michael's answer.

Just wanted to clarify:
As soon as the condition(`rand_num > 8`) is met, the event `condition_flag` is triggered and set to succeed(). This in turn makes the suspended `car` process to resume. And after that, we are resetting the event `condition_flag` to detect another trigger & succeed(). Is my understanding correct?

Also, since I wanted to simulate more cars, a slight modification in code:

```
import simpy
import random

num_of_cars = 2
condition_flag = [None] * num_of_cars


def car(env, car_id):
    while True:
        global condition_flag
        # wait for the condition to become true
        print('wait for event')
        yield condition_flag[car_id]
        # reset condition flag
        condition_flag[car_id] = simpy.Event(env)
        print('event fired and reset')

        print('Start parking at %d' % env.now)
        parking_duration = 5
        yield env.timeout(parking_duration)

        print('Start driving at %d' % env.now)
        trip_duration = 2
        yield env.timeout(trip_duration)


def some_condition(env):
    while True:
        global condition_flag
        rand_num = random.randrange(0, num_of_cars)
        print(rand_num)
        condition_flag[rand_num].succeed()
        '''
        if rand_num > 8:
            print('condition meet ',env.now)
            # need to check if event has been reset
            if condition_flag.triggered:
                print('event has not been reset yet')
            else:
                condition_flag.succeed()
        '''
        yield env.timeout(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start')
    env = simpy.Environment()
    condition_flag = simpy.Event(env)
    #env.process(car(env))
    for i in range(num_of_cars):
        env.process(car(env, I))
    env.process(some_condition(env))
    env.run(until=50)
    print('stop')
```

The above code is giving the following error after it is run:

```
root@testuser-Vostro-3902:~/AtAI/Rack_Warehouse/LoRaSimulators/lorasim# python simple2.py
start
wait for event
wait for event
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple2.py", line 13, in car
    yield condition_flag[car_id]
TypeError: 'Event' object does not support indexing

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple2.py", line 53, in <module>
    env.run(until=50)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/simpy/core.py", line 254, in run
    self.step()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/simpy/core.py", line 206, in step
    raise exc
TypeError: 'Event' object does not support indexing
```

Is there any thing wrong I am doing? Why a process is not able to yield on an event that is a member of list of events?

Answer (score 0):

When you yield on a event your process waits for that event to fires.  You can trigger when that event fires by calling that event's succeed, or fail methods.

I updated your code to use events instead of a flag, see below

```
import simpy
import random

condition_flag = None


def car(env):
    while True:
        global condition_flag
        # wait for the condition to become true
        print('wait for event')
        yield condition_flag
        # reset condition flag
        condition_flag = simpy.Event(env)
        print('event fired and reset')

        print('Start parking at %d' % env.now)
        parking_duration = 5
        yield env.timeout(parking_duration)

        print('Start driving at %d' % env.now)
        trip_duration = 2
        yield env.timeout(trip_duration)


def some_condition(env):
    while True:
        global condition_flag
        rand_num = random.randrange(0, 10)
        print(rand_num)
        if rand_num > 8:
            print('condition meet ',env.now)
            # need to check if event has been reset
            if condition_flag.triggered:
                print('event has not been reset yet')
            else:
                condition_flag.succeed()
        yield env.timeout(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start')
    env = simpy.Environment()
    condition_flag = simpy.Event(env)
    env.process(car(env))
    env.process(some_condition(env))
    env.run(until=50)
    print('stop')
```

Comment: Also note that more than one process can yield on the same event.

Comment: Hi @Michael, Please see the above edit. I was not able to extend it and wait for a list of events.

Comment: I think if you just add more cars to my code it will work just fine.  All the cars will yield and resume on the same event.

looking at your code
at line: condition_flag = [None] * num_of_cars
you create a list of None

in if __name__ == '__main__'
line:
condition_flag = simpy.Event(env)
is overwriting that list with just one event

if you change that line to:
condition_flag = []

and inside the loop that creates the cars add:
condition_flag.append(simpy.Event(env))

That will get you to the next error